# User "?" in fuelphp router

Tags: fuelphp, fuelphp-routing

I config a router

```
'users/user(/fields=:fname,:lname,:age)?'   => 'users/user/$1/$2/$3',
```

used: /users/user/fields=John,Smith,33 (fname = John, lname = Smith, age = 33)

I want config like
users/user?fields=John,Smith,33

but I can't use "?" in a router.

Answer (score 0):

Routing does not include GET parameters as they are not considered part of the URI. For the functionality that you desire you would be better off specifying a closure as the right hand side of the route and returning the constructed string.

```
'users/user' => function(){ 
    return 'users/user/' //Custom logic goes here to build the internal URI
}
```